# Cloud functions onCreate Trigger function failing HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When I try to add trigger for Firestore OnCreate the deployment fails for HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors.

Basically I want to write to a new doc if the record is created in different collection. but get the userId. this involves 2 write and 1 read. not sure if it is efficient way

But the log and the error has no detail on what the error is

Here's my code

```
'use strict';

import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

const requestPromise = require('request-promise');

admin.initializeApp();
const firestore = admin.firestore();
const cors = require('cors')({
    origin: true,
});


exports.joinCommunity = functions.region('europe-west2').firestore.document('users/{userId}/community')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
        const data = snap.data();
        const communityRef = firestore.doc(`community/${data['cid']}`);
        const user = {
            uid: context.params.userId,
            joined_on: context.timestamp
        }
        return communityRef.collection('members').doc(context.params.userId).set(user, { merge: true });
    });
```

Appreciate the support or pointer

> **Solution**: The problem was that I had used the Collection path instead of the document path. Changing the **.document(users/{userId}/community')** to **.document('users/{userId}/community/{communityId}')** fixed the error

> **Additionally**: Also note in my code i have used Javascript way of export in typescript. Not an issue but the right way yo use it **export const joinCommunity**

Comment: If you're having problems deploying, and the error is not helpful, contact Firebase support for assistance. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Weird thing is the error message was not relevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To define a Cloud Firestore trigger, you need to specify a **document path**. With `users/{userId}/community` you are specifying a collection path.

So either you trigger your CF when a document is created in the `users` collection (with `users/{userId}`) or in the `community` subcollection (with `users/{userId}/community/{docId}`).

---

Have also a look at the following GitHub page https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/typescript-getting-started and in particular at the different ways (between JavaScript and TypeScript) for importing the Cloud Functions SDK and Admin SDK modules and for exporting the Cloud Functions.

Comment: changing the collection path to document path helped to fix the issue. Thank you. also the import and export changes was useful. Thanks a lot